# How to load specific moment locales with browserify

Tags: momentjs, browserify, angular-moment

I have an angular application built in Visual Studio 2017. I'm using npm, gulp, and browserify to help me manage dependencies, bundling, and minification. Everything had been going along well until I tried to pull in moment, moment-timezone, and angular-moment, when I started having trouble getting these libraries to play nice.

I'm assuming that the issue is related to the way these libraries are being included in my application due to some mistake or bug with the way I'm using npm, gulp, browserify, or the require('...') statements. So, it seems like it'd be helpful for me to explain how I'm doing that.

First, in VS, I added a node configuration file to the project (package.json) and it contains a list of all of my dependencies that will be installed through npm. So, for example, my package.json looks something like this:

```
{
"property": value,
"otherProperty": otherValue,
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.8",
    "angular-ui-router": "1.0.3",
    "jquery": "3.1.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",     
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.13",
    "angular-moment": "1.0.1"
    }
}
```

Now, that makes npm go ahead and download everything and stick it in my node_modules folder, but it doesn't actually include anything in my application. So there's a gulp task similar to the following:

```
var dependencies = Object.keys(packageJson && packageJson.dependencies || {});
browserify({cache: {}, packageCache: {} }})
    .require(dependencies)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source(js/siteLibs.js))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
```

Ok, so if that gulp task works correctly, I'll have a file called siteLibs.js that contains all of the js from my npm dependencies, and then I can just make a single script tag to reference siteLibs.js.

The next part, I'm a little hazy on, but do I still have to have an actual require('...') statement in my app for moment, angular-moment, and moment-timezone? If it is required, why? What is it doing?

Now, once at this point, I should be able to go ahead and let my angular app take a dependency on moment, moment-timezone, or angular-moment, and, indeed I can. The issue is that when I call moment.locales(), which is supposed to return a list of all loaded locales, it has naught but 'en-US'. Ok, that's expected because I never loaded any locales. So if I go in my app and say:

```
require('moment/locales/en-gb');
require('moment/locales/en-au');
require('moment/locales/fr-ca');
```

It makes no difference. The only loaded locale is en-US. What is the right way to go about getting those additional locales loaded given that I'm using npm, gulp, and browserify?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this in moment's documentation

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browserify/

Comment: Yeah, either I don't understand the workaround exactly, or I'm not doing it right. I've added the require statements (in the app.js), but this doesn't actually get them loaded. moment.locales() still just returns 'en-US'. It DOES get the locale-specific javascript files included in my site's js, but apparently they're not actually loaded as far as moment knows. I'm wondering if it's a conflict with the moment object from moment-timezonne or angular-moment or something?

Comment: Definitely seems like an angular-moment thing, I'm not familiar with the library. Just skimming their docs here: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment - I think this is where your issues are coming in.

Check out your angular.module.config file, I think you might want to make sure that's aligned with what you're looking for (locale-related issue posted here: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/issues/259).